# How do I add support for the "hevc" format to VLC?

Tags: codec, vlc, format

[image: VLC Error Console: No suitable decoder module: VLC does not support the audio or video format “hevc". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.]

> No suitable decoder module:
>   VLC does not support the audio or video format “hevc".
>   Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

Comment: I was specifically looking for VLC, and that question didn't come up (even though it _does_ have it as an alternative in the answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Install the HEVC VLC Plugin

You will need to install `libde265`, which is an open source implementation of the h.265 video codec, or HEVC.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Comment: @Lewis Goddard +1 , works also for Ubuntu14.04